# multiple constraints on a table what am I doing wrong

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm having trouble with one of my tables having two constraints, here is my code I'm quite new to this and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, that 8> isn't in my code I just left it there to show which line it was. I have three other tables cust, item, and order which all are working fine, Should I be adding the 2nd constraint a different way? It seems to work without the 2nd constraint

```
    SQL> create table ocontent(
    onum integer not null,
    inum integer not null,
    qord integer not null,
    qpend integer not null,
    primary key(onum, inum),
    constraint fk_ocontnt_o foreign key(onum) references ordr(onum),
    8>constraint fk_ocontnt_i foreign key(inum) references item(inum));

                                *
    ERROR at line 8:
    ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type
```

Comment: What's `desc item`?

Comment: If you remove the first constraint, is that works for you?

Comment: Post the table definitions of the `ordr` and `item` tables. It's likely that the primary key `onum` or `inum` types aren't integers

Comment: I'd bet onum is wrong size.  I'm thinking bigint is more appropriate for an order number.

Comment: Folks, why are you all looking at `onum` when the error message is very clearly at **line 8** which is for `inum`? It's not rocket science.

Comment: @danny117 - in Oracle, `INTEGER` is a synonym for `NUMBER(38)`. That is the longest possible number size in Oracle; not sure what you meant by bigint, but that doesn't exist in Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the update mathguy.  Didn't see the Oracle tag.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the `inum` column in the `item` table has `integer` as type. 
Both columns should have the same types in order to create a foreign key.